# MySQL datatype INT(11) whereas UNSIGNED INT(10)?

Tags: mysql, types, int, unsigned-integer

in MySQL if we create a field dataType of `INT` and does not specify any length/values then it  automatically became `int(11)` and if we set the attribute **UNSIGNED** or **UNSIGNED ZEROFILL** then it turns into `int(10)`

Where does this  **length(1)** goes?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

int value can be -2147483648 these are 11 digits so the default ***display*** size is 11

unsigned int does not allow negative numbers so by default it need only ***display*** size 10

As the documentation below shows, the number of bits required to store SIGNED INT and UNSIGNED INT is the same, the range of storable numbers is merely shifted:

> Unsigned type can be used to permit
>   only nonnegative numbers in a column
>   or when you need a larger upper
>   numeric range for the column. For
>   example, if an INT column is UNSIGNED,
>   the size of the column's range is the
>   same but its endpoints shift from
>   -2147483648 and 2147483647 up to 0 and 4294967295.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html

Comment: Thanks a ton.. btw i m also from Bikaner :)

Comment: @diEcho: Great, We both are from same place. Nice to talk you on SO

Comment: Hello Rajasthanis :).. Your post still helping us :)

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the numeric value (10 or 11) isn't tied to the memory size allocated for this column, but the number of characters allows to form the number? So setting a column as UNSIGNED INT(11) won't allow any more number than an UNSIGNED INT(10)?

Answer (score 24):

According to [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html), this number is merely the *display width*.

> For example, INT(4) specifies an INT with a display width of four
>   digits.
>
> **The display width does not constrain the range of values that can be
>   stored in the column**. Nor does it prevent values wider than the column
>   display width from being displayed correctly. For example, a column
>   specified as SMALLINT(3) has the usual SMALLINT range of -32768 to
>   32767, and values outside the range permitted by three digits are
>   displayed in full using more than three digits.

The *default* display width for an `UNSIGNED` `INT` is one fewer than that for a non-`UNSIGNED` `INT` simply because you will never be displaying a `-` character.

Note that you can still specify whatever display width you like. This is just the *default*.

The use of the term "digits" in the documentation is slightly misleading here.

Comment: That is great. It means the display width, not the range of values.

Answer (score 10):

Just incase anyone doesn't quite understand [Shakti's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256560/datatype-by-default-is-int11-whereas-unsigned-becomes-int10-in-mysql/5256610#5256610) (as I didn't). Here's a visual representation of why:

```
 Signed minimum:
 - 2 1 4 7 4 8 3 6 4  8
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11

 Unsigned max (also the signed max):
 4 2 9 4 9 6 7 2 9 5
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Comment: Spaces to save the value have nothing to do with it. This is only the _display width_ and does not constrain the stored value in any way.

Comment: The signed max is not 2^32-1 but 2^31-1, as you have one bit for the sign, so unsigned max != signed max.